# Firebase JS Secure Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I've been doing some research about secure tokens and Firebase JS, but I have ready some conflicting information, so I will just ask my question directly. Is it possible to handle secure sessions with Firebase using Javascript? For practice, I'm creating a little web game that will rely on Firebase to synchronize each client, and I'm wondering the process for doing so securely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you define a "secure session". There are two issues at play here.

1. Transport level security: The Firebase JS client communicates with the servers over HTTPS. Additonally, Firebase has a security rules system that lets you specify which clients can read and write which data.
2. Application level integrity: However, the client is free to make whatever changes it is authorized to, even if they are *not* triggered by your JS code. For example, in a web page, I can open the developer console and use the Firebase API to make data changes that aren't part of the web page's logic.

To tackle the latter, you'll need a server where you can run trusted code to enforce game state. For instance, every move made by a client in the game should be first put into a "pending" queue. A server process should monitor all pending changes, validate them and them move them to a "final" game state location which will be the authoritative game state.

Comment: Note that all types of games don't need sophisticated logic that would warrant a server process. We have a tetris example that's entirely client side: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/tetris